# How can I take data from one an input field of one form and use it to populate the same input type in a different form using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have 2 sign up forms on a site. One is at the top that opens up in a modal and is a multi step form starting at the input for the email address.The code for that form is as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signup-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signup-updates-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="#" role="form" method="post" action="sendform.php">
    <!-- #first_step -->
    <div id="step_one">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><p class="icon-close-btn"><a href="#"></a></p></span></button>
        <h4 class="modalsignup-title white" id="signup-updates-modal">Step 1 / 4 Option Care Information Updates</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Want to learn more about Option Care home infusion services? Please provide your email address to receive custom information and updates.</p>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <label  class="col-md-3 control-label" for="email_address">Email Address</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_address" placeholder="Email" name="signupemail" required />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-arrow btn-nextstep" id="step_one_submit">Next Step</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- #second_step -->
    <div id="step_two" data-toggle="tab">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><p class="icon-close-btn"><a href="#"></a></p></span></button>
        <h4 class="modalsignup-title white" id="signup-updates-modal">Step 2 / 4 Option Care Information Updates</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Please tell us more about yourself, so we can send you the right information.</p>
        <div class="form-group">

            <label  class="control-label" for="step_two_radio">I am a:</label>

            <!-- <label  class="control-label" for="step_two_radio">I am a:</label> -->
            <div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" placeholder="p2radio1" value="PatientOrCaregiver">
                  Patient or Caregiver</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="ClinicianOrReferrer">
                  Clinician or Referrer</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="PotentialRecruit">
                  Job Applicant</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="PharmaceuticalPartner">
                  Pharmaceutical Partner </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios5" value="PayerPartner">
                  Payer Partner </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios6" value="Other">
                  Other </label>
                 <div class="voffset2"></div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="other_I_a" placeholder="About you"/>
              </div>

            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left btn-arrowback btn-previous" id="step_two_previous" >Previous Step</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-arrow btn-nextstep" id="step_two_submit">>Continue</button> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-arrow btn-nextstep" id="step_two_submit">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- #THRID STEP -->
    <!-- #THRID STEP -->

    <div id="step_three">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><p class="icon-close-btn"><a href="#"></a></p></span></button>
        <h4 class="modalsignup-title white" id="signup-updates-modal">Step 3 / 4 Option Care Information Updates</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>So that we can better assist you, please tell us if you are a current Option Care home infusion patient.</p>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label  class="control-label" for="inputEmail3">Are you a current customer of Option Care?</label>
          <div>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="step_three_radio" id="inlineRadio1" value="CustomerYes">
              Yes </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="step_three_radio" id="inlineRadio2" value="CustomerNo">
              No </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="step_three_radio" id="inlineRadio3" value="NotApplicable">
              Not applicable </label>
              <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="messagestep3" /> -->
              <div id="messagestep3"></div>

          </div>
          <!-- <div id="messagestep3"></div> -->


        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="step_three_b">
          <label  class="control-label" for="inputEmail4">You’ve indicated that you are not a current Option Care home infusion patient. Are you interested in using Option Care home infusion services in the next 6 months?</label>
          <div>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="step_three_radio2" id="inlineRadio4" value="InterestedYes">
              Yes </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="step_three_radio2" id="inlineRadio5" value="InterestedNo">
              No </label>
              <div id="messagestep3b"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left btn-arrowback btn-previous" id="step_three_previous" >Previous Step</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-arrow btn-nextstep" id="step_three_submit">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- #fourth_step -->
    <div id="step_four">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><p class="icon-close-btn"><a href="#"></a></p></span></button>
        <h4 class="modalsignup-title white" id="signup-updates-modal">Step 4 / 4 Option Care Information Updates</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Select the therapeutic service(s) you are interested in learning more about. Please check all that apply.</p>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label  class="control-label" for="inputEmail3">If you are interested in a specific therapeutic area, please select it from the list below:</label>
          <div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="AntiInfectives">
                Anti-infectives (AI)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Bleeding disorders" name="step_four_checkbox">
                Bleeding disorders (BD)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="HeartFailure" name="step_four_checkbox">
                Heart failure (HF)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Immunoglobulin" name="step_four_checkbox">
                Immunoglobulin (IG)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="NutritionSupport" name="step_four_checkbox">
                Nutrition support (NS)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="OtherTherapeutic" name="step_four_checkbox">
                Other </label>
                <div class="voffset2"></div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="other_therapeutic_area" name="" value="" placeholder="So that we may better assist you, please tell us what services you are interested in."/>
            </div>
            <div id="step-four-input"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left btn-arrowback btn-previous" id="step_four_previous" >Previous Step</button>
   <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" id="step_four_previous">Previous Step</button> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-arrow btn-nextstep" id="step_four_submit" value="insert">Submit</button>
             </div>
          </div>
       </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- /Modal HTML -->
```

Next I have a second sign up form at the bottom of the site in a call to action that has only the email input and when the button is clicked opens the modal to the second form. The code for that form is a follows:

```
<form action="sendform.php" method="post" name="contact-form" class=" indline-form" id="main-contact-form">
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" name="signupemail" id="bottomemail" required="required" class="form-control"   value="Enter your email address..."   
   onfocus="(this.value == 'Enter your email address...') && (this.value = '')"
   onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'Enter your email address...')" />
          <button required="required" class="btn btn-arrow"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup-modal" id="bottom_form_submit" class="modal-toggle">Subscribe</a></button>
      </div>
 </form>
```

Now my question is is there any JQuery or javascript I can use to take the value from the bottom sign up form's email input field and place it into the signup form in the modal at the top's email input field?

Comment: Yeah of course, just store the value of the first field in a variable, then set it as the .val() of the other field. You can bind it to an event like a click etc.

Comment: @AndyHolmes do you have any code on that for me to reference?

Comment: The answers below are the main bulk of what you need, just look at binding it in an `on('click', function{})` call

Comment: Just to clarify, are these two forms placed inside the same page? Or which one opens in a different browser page/tab/instance?

Comment: @AndyHolmes I got it to work by using this:  `$('#bottom_form_submit').click(function (e) {
            $('#step_one').css("display", "none");
            $('#step_two').css("display", "block");
            $('#email_address').val($('#bottomemail').val());
    });`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
jQuery('#email_address').val(jQuery('#bottomemail').val());
```

Comment: Might be worth showing an example of a binding too? I assume he'd like the value to be set on click of the button

Comment: @MikeL5799 Can you edit your question inserting what you have so far? Where are you placing your code on page? Also, how are you invoking your code?

Comment: @AndyHolmes the page will not be submitted prior the code above executes? In that case would not be better to bind on the blur event?

Comment: Thank you so much @Peterson I got it using this: ` $('#bottom_form_submit').click(function (e) {
            $('#step_one').css("display", "none");
            $('#step_two').css("display", "block");
            $('#email_address').val($('#bottomemail').val());
    });

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the value from first field

```
var value = $("#idFirstElement").val();
```

and set the value to second field.

```
$("#IdSecondField").val(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#email_address,#bottomemail').keyup(function() {
    $('#email_address,#bottomemail').val($(this).val());
});
```

This will keep the two inputs in sync by copying the value of the one being changed to both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#bottomemail').on('input', function() {
    $('#email_address').val( this.value );
});
```

As in the demo below:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#bottomemail').on('input', function() {
        $('#email_address').val( this.value );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="signup-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signup-updates-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="#" role="form" method="post" action="sendform.php">
<!-- #first_step -->
    <div id="step_one">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><p class="icon-close-btn"><a href="#"></a></p></span></button>
        <h4 class="modalsignup-title white" id="signup-updates-modal">Step 1 / 4 Option Care Information Updates</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Want to learn more about Option Care home infusion services? Please provide your email address to receive custom information and updates.</p>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <label  class="col-md-3 control-label" for="email_address">Email Address</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email_address" placeholder="Email" name="signupemail" required />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-arrow btn-nextstep" id="step_one_submit">Next Step</button>
      </div>
    </div>
        <!-- ........ -->
        <!-- ........ -->
        </div>
      </div>



<form action="sendform.php" method="post" name="contact-form" class=" indline-form" id="main-contact-form">
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" name="signupemail" id="bottomemail" required="required" class="form-control"   value="Enter your email address..."   
   onfocus="(this.value == 'Enter your email address...') && (this.value = '')"
   onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'Enter your email address...')" />
          <button required="required" class="btn btn-arrow"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup-modal" id="bottom_form_submit" class="modal-toggle">Subscribe</a></button>
      </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: That's nice and clean, wasn't aware of `input`

Comment: Glad I could be of help. :) Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I like Skymt's idea of using `keyup`, but to give my 2 cents worth, here's what I was talking about in my comments on the question. I've used the `click` of a button to show functionality you could do as Peterson say's and use `blur`:

HTML:

```
<form action="">
  <label for="">Input 1</label><input id="input1" type="text">
  <button id="trigger">Trigger</button>
</form>

<form action="">
  <label for="">Input 2</label><input id="input2" type="text">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trigger').on('click', function(){
        var value = $('#input1').val();
        $('#input2').val(value);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dg8u3ng1/